# Using backreference as replacement string in JQ

Tags: regex, jq

Assuming I want to extract the time part of a date/time string on the shell I can do something like:

```
echo "2021-06-10T10:42:30.016+0200" | sed 's|.*T\(.*\)\..*|\1|g'
```

This returns

```
10:42:30
```

How can I achieve the same with `jq` and `sub()`?
I'm missing the right syntax. I was not able to find any good examples. E.g. I've been trying:

```
jq '<myid> | sub(".*T(.*)\\..*"; "\1")'
jq '<myid> | sub(".*T(.*)\\..*"; "$1")'
jq '<myid> | sub(".*T\\(.*\\)\\..*"; "\1")'
```

But none of this returns back what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JQ we use [named capture groups](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC16) for that.

```
sub(".*T(?<x>.*)\\..*"; .x)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you may remove all up to `T` and all the text starting with (and including) a dot with `.*T|\.[^.]*$` regex:

```sh
s='{"node":"2021-06-10T10:42:30.016+0200"}'
jq '.node |= gsub(".*T|\\.[^.]*$"; "")' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
{
  "node": "10:42:30"
}
```

*Pattern details*:

- `.*T` - any text and then `T`
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.`
- `$` - end of string.